# Add authentification with Google in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I already implemented authentication with Apple and Microsoft, now I want to implement with Google but I need help.
Here are the steps already taken:
Go to the Google Cloud Console.
Create a new project or select an existing one.
Configure OAuth 2.0 Credentials
Create a new OAuth client ID.

#### AuthService:

```
 IdentityClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
     .Create(Constants.ApplicationId)
     .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
     .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
     .Build();
   
     public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationTokenGoogle()
     {
         try
         {
             var authService = ServiceHelper.GetService<AuthService>();
   
             if (authService.IsAuthenticated)
             {
                 return new AuthenticationToken();
             }
   
             var result = await authService.IdentityClient
                 .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                 .WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
                 .ExecuteAsync();
   
             if (result != null)
             {
                 authService.IsAuthenticated = true;
   
                 return new AuthenticationToken();
             }
             ...
         }
     }
```

#### In the controller :

```
   [HttpPost("GoogleAuthenticate")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleAuthenticate([FromBody] GoogleAuthRequestModel googleAuthRequest)
   {
       try
       {
           var result = await _usersRepository.AuthenticateWithGoogleAsync(googleAuthRequest.Token);
   
   ...
       }
   }
```

#### This is the code in UserRepository in the Business classe library :

```
   
    public virtual async Task<UsersEntity> AuthenticateWithGoogleAsync(string googleToken)
    {
            var validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(googleToken);
   
            if (validPayload != null)
            {
                var userId = validPayload.Subject;
                var existingUser = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IdentityId == userId);
   
                if (existingUser != null)
                {
                    return existingUser;
                }
                else
                {
                    var newUser = new UsersEntity
                    {
                        IdentityId = userId,
                    };
   
                    await AddAsync(newUser);
                    await SaveAsync();
   
                    return newUser;
                }
```

In GoogleAuthRequestModel I have : public string Token { get; set; }

When I get to var result = await authService.IdentityClient of AuthService, I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
The IdentityClient is null

Can you also confirm that the implemented code is correct for authentication with Google

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, but it's not supposed to show me a page to connect with Google?

Comment: You do understand that IdentityClient being null has something to do with your builder creation yeah? and you might have to find what you are doing wrong there

Comment: Correct, but I can't find the error